# Fabric orderer to peer configuration for deliver RPC

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

We've a below network setup for hyperledger fabric:
3 Ordering Service nodes, 4 Kafka brokers and 3 Organizations (2 peers in each organization)

Requirement is - we need to make sure leader peer from each organization is receiving blocks via deliver RPC from a "specific" ordering service node.

How can we configure a specific ordering service node for peers in fabric?

Answer (score 0):

There's no "magic" way to configure something like this in Fabric.  The orderer endpoint information is stored in the system channel so normally all 3 of the Ordering Service endpoints would be in their so that any peer from any organization is aware of all the endpoints (for fault tolerance).

With the current Kafka-based ordering service, you *might* be able to achieve what you want by only setting a single endpoint in the orderer addresses section and then making sure that each organization resolved that DNS name to the specific endpoint desired.

Comment: I'm using a Kafka-based ordering service, but how do we configure it to use a specific endpoint per organization?